# How to infer the eigenvalue distribution from matrix where each entry has a known Gaussian distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, machine-learning, bayesian, random-matrices

## Problem

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $X_{ij} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_{ij}, \sigma_{ij}^2 I)$

Find the eigenvalue distribution using whatever you can.

## Background

In my field, I have a Bayesian inference framework that will obtain the $X$ distribution, but what we really need is the eigenvalue distribution of the matrix $X$.

## Question

1. Is this problem well defined?
2. Is the only way to infer it through sampling in such **high dimensional** space and then for each realization of the matrix, do the eigenvalue decomposition?

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of [Wigner's semi-circle law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html) which is applicable to symmetric random matrices

Comment: but that is for symmetric matrix, right?

Comment: yes but at the bottom of the page there's a link to [Girko's circular law](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GirkosCircularLaw.html) which seems to cover the general case